# Can DataType.Currency DataAnnotation be used in a multi currency environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

using:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

I get a nice looking formatting text: `$U 4.882,50`

Now, what if I have multiple currencies on the site, let's say one product I'm showing in $U and other in U$S ? I know that data annotation works with culture information, I guess I can't use DataType.Currency in my situation or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currency annotation can be used. However it is just telling MVC which display or editor template to use. As you say current template uses the system currency. You would have to provide custom editor template or display template and some other way to determine the currency symbol to display

Look [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) at how to provide your own implementations

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")